# Gurobi, python and tsp from adjacence matix

Tags: python, gurobi

I'm trying to solve a tsp problem from and adjacency matrix. For that, I use Gurobi. It seems that I don't understand what is print by python and why it's not correct.

Can somoene help me to see my fault?

Here is my code:

```
import folium
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
import math
from itertools import combinations,product
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
mat = [[0,1,3,1,2,2],
       [1,0,5,6,4,1],
       [3,5,0,1,2,3],
       [1,6,1,0,2,4],
       [2,4,2,2,0,1],
       [2,1,3,4,1,0]]
def distance(city1, city2):
    for i in range(len(mat[0])):
        for j in range(len(mat[0])):
            if(i==int(city1)):
                if( j == int(city2)):
                    print(mat[i][j])
                    return mat[i][j]
dist = {(c1, c2): distance(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in product(capitals, capitals) if c1 != c2}
def subtourelim(model, where):
    if where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
        # make a list of edges selected in the solution
        vals = model.cbGetSolution(model._vars)
        selected = gp.tuplelist((i, j) for i, j in model._vars.keys()
                             if vals[i, j] > 0.5)
        # find the shortest cycle in the selected edge list
        tour = subtour(selected)
        if len(tour) < len(capitals):
            # add subtour elimination constr. for every pair of cities in subtour
            model.cbLazy(gp.quicksum(model._vars[i, j] for i, j in combinations(tour, 2))
                         <= len(tour)-1)
# Given a tuplelist of edges, find the shortest subtour
def subtour(edges):
    unvisited = capitals[:]
    cycle = capitals[:] # Dummy - guaranteed to be replaced
    while unvisited:  # true if list is non-empty
        thiscycle = []
        neighbors = unvisited
        while neighbors:
            current = neighbors[0]
            thiscycle.append(current)
            unvisited.remove(current)
            neighbors = [j for i, j in edges.select(current, '*')
                         if j in unvisited]
        if len(thiscycle) <= len(cycle):
            cycle = thiscycle # New shortest subtour
    return cycle
m = gp.Model()
# Variables: is city 'i' adjacent to city 'j' on the tour?
vars = m.addVars(dist.keys(), obj=dist, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='e')
for i, j in vars.keys():
    m.addConstr(vars[j, i] == vars[i, j])  # edge in opposite direction
# Constraints: two edges incident to each city
m.addConstrs(vars.sum(c, '*') == 2 for c in capitals)
# Optimize the model
m._vars = vars
m.Params.lazyConstraints = 1
m.optimize(subtourelim)
```

I'am a little bit lost and it's my first post here. So, forgive me if it's unclear. Moreover, I'm not native english, so maybe, there are some error in my language.

Comment: Please try to reformulate your question and post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you try first to solve your problem without optimisation? As your matrix `mat` is not so big, I think you can work without `gurobipy` for a first step